# node second mysql query not running

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to run two queries with node.js on the same table, but I can't seem to get the second to run (the queries are just examples, I know this is a silly way to do this):

```
async.waterfall(
    [
        function(callback) {
            connection.query('SELECT tail FROM tails;', function(err, rows, fields) {
                console.log("All results:",rows);
                return callback(null, 1);
            });
        },

        function(ret, callback) {
            console.log("ret: ",ret);

            connection.query('SELECT id FROM tails;', function(err, rows, fields) {
                console.log("All ID results:",rows);
                return callback(null, 'data');
            });
        }
    ],
    function(err, result) {
        console.log("waterfall function. Result:",result);
    }
);
```

I turned on logging all queries on mysql, and only the first query shows up in the log.  I tried nesting callbacks before using async.waterfall but I get the same behavior.

I do get the line `ret: 1`, but I get `All ID results: undefined`.

If I move the query out of this block so it's asynchronous then everything works properly, but I need the results from the first query in order to run the second.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: try checking if `err` is defined in your second function, might find something there

Comment: Good point.  I previously checked `err` for the first query, but never for the second.  The connection was being closed before the second query went through, so I had to serialize the close along with the queries.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Nir Levy mentioned in his comment, always be sure to check `err` for everything as that's where the answer was spelled out.

Outside this waterfall I have a command to close the connection, which was being called in parallel.  Adding the close to the waterfall solved the problem.